# Attempting to understand what a "Face" in planar graph to count faces correctly

Tags: graph-theory

How does a graph with one vertex have one face? I understand Euler's theorem polyhedron $V-E+F=2$. However, I don't understand what a polytope and hyperplane is so I can't understand the topologically complicated definition of face. If I lookup a dumbed-down version of what a "face" is, it's too hand-wavy.

Let us say I have the following graph with $6$ vertices, $6$ edges, and therefore $2$ faces. I see how the triangular-like region formed by $4$ vertices makes up a face. I however don't understand how the extra 1 face was counted. See image drawn below:

[image]

Next, let's remove an edge below. Now the transformed graph below has $1$ face total. How the heck did this happen? How does it have $1$ face and not $2$?

See below:

[image: FIGURE TWO. A THREE CYCLE UNIONED WITH A SINGLE SOLITARY EDGE. FOUR TOTAL NODES IN THE GRAPH.]

Recall wolfram's:

> Generally, a face is a component polygon, polyhedron, or polytope. A two-dimensional face thus has vertices and edges, and can be used to make cells. More formally, a face is the intersection of an $n$-dimensional polytope with a tangent hyperplane. Zero-dimensional faces are known as polyhedron vertices (nodes), one-dimensional faces as polyhedron edges, $(n-2)-D$ faces as ridges, and $(n-1)$-dimensional faces as facets.

and the "Face" in dumbed-down speak

```
 is regions bounded by edges, including the outer, infinitely large region
```

What infinitely large region does wikipedia talk about on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph? Is every graph bounded by an infinitely larger graph? Does that mean that an infinitely large graph is a non-existent because it is an element and subset of itself and therefore not an element of itself? Russell's paradox

Comment: Isn't a face something of the form $\overline C$ where $C$ is a connected component of $\mathbb R^2$ minus the embedding?

Comment: Your second image has two faces. Note that the graph has 5 vertices and 5 edges, giving equality for $(5) - (5) + F = 2$. Also, the "infinitely large region" Wikipedia mentions in the region "surrounding" the graph.

Comment: The second image has 6 vertices. I removed one edge without removing the endpoints of the edge.

Comment: I can remove an edge without removing endpoints. that smudge is a vertex. 6-(6-1)+x=2. x=1=faces.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Euler's Formula only applies to _connected_ graphs. If we try to apply it to non-connected graphs, we have the situation where a group of $n$ vertices with no edges would imply there exist $2 - n$ faces, and we would have to make sense of "negative" faces.

Comment: For fun, you might find [this excerpt](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kpmann/Lakatos.pdf) on Euler's Formula interesting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your second image, the floating disconnected vertex is throwing off your total.    Euler's Theorem only applies to *connected* graphs -- otherwise you could arbitrarily add as many isolated vertices as you want and make $F-E+V$ come out to any arbitrary whole number greater than or equal to $2$.

Comment: A disconnected vertex has zero lines coming out of it. In the picture, every node has degree at least equal to one. That is, the degree of a disconnected vertex is zero and the degree of every node shown in the diagram is at least one. The graph is ***connected***. Let $G.VS$ be the vertex set of graph $G$. We have that $\forall V, W \in G.VS$, there exists a path from vertex $V$ to vertex $W$. Thus, graph $G$ is ***connected*** by the definition of connectivity. There are no isolated vertices in the diagram provided. An isolated vertex has degree zero.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone the original image in the problem had an actually disconnected vertex.  The problem was edited at some point in the past and the original hand-drawn image was replaced with the current one. You can see evidence of this in the comments under OP: "that smudge is a vertex".

Answer (score 6):

The last face is the entire plane that isn’t in the other faces you mentioned, which they called the outer, infinitely large region. In the case of a single point, it is the entire plane. A face can be thought of as a region of space such that you ca go anywhere in the region without having to cross over a line. Also, Euler's Theorem only applies to connected graphs.

[image: Planar cube]

As an example, here is a planar graph representing a cube. You'll notice that the left image tells you to remove the bottom, but it should say that the area that isn’t labeled "side" or "top" is the bottom of the cube.

Answer (score 0):

### First Observation

I think you might have miscounted the number of vertices and edges for one of your examples.

Let us count the number of vertices and edges.

---

### Figure One

[image: figure one]

$
\begin{matrix}
\mathtt{VERTEX\_COUNT} & - & \mathtt{EDGE\_COUNT}  & + & \mathtt{FACE\_COUNT}  & = & 2 \\
|G.VS| & - & |G.ES| & + & |G.FS| & = & 2 \\
V & - & E & + & F & = & 2 \\
6 & - & 6 & + & 2 & = & 2 \\
\end{matrix}
$

---

### Figure Two

[image]

Figure two has one less edge and one less vertex than figure one.

$
\begin{matrix}
\mathtt{VERTEX\_COUNT} & - & \mathtt{EDGE\_COUNT}  & + & \mathtt{FACE\_COUNT}  & = & 2 \\
|G.VS| & - & |G.ES| & + & |G.FS| & = & 2 \\
V & - & E & + & F & = & 2 \\
5 & - & 5 & + & 2 & = & 2 \\
\end{matrix}
$

---

### Some Remarks

Let $G$ be a large complicated graph and let $C$ be a cycle in graph $G$.

Usually, cycle $C$ is a face if and only if for every pair of vertices in  cycle $C$, if there is an edge between those two vertices in graph $G$, then there is an edge between those same two vertices in cycle $C$.

In other words, we cannot have an edge from from one side of a face, to the other side of the face, crossing through the middle of the face.

However, a lot of graph theorists talk about the "***outer face***".

The **outer*** face is usually what you get if you go around the outside of the whole thing and ignore the inner parts.

Alternatively, the **outer** face is the bottom of a three dimensional shape that has flat slides.

If you were like a bird, or in a helicopter, looking down on the Egyptian pyramid, you would see four faces. However, a pyramid has five faces, because the fifth face is the bottom of the pyramid.

---

### Figure Three

Here is one last example of a graph with some faces. Here, the faces are labeled.

Although seven faces are obvious, most mathematicians would say that there are 8 faces, because they include the "**outer face**" or the bottom of the shape.

[image: a picture of a shape with eight faces]